# Custom number picker inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

Please, help me with using `NumberPicker` from https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker.
I have fragment inside which I have button. After clicking button I want to show my number picker (as a pop-up, not new screen). 
So what I did:
I created `NumberPickerCustomDialog`

```
public class NumberPickerCustomDialog extends DialogFragment {
Context context;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // get context
    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    // make dialog object
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // inflate our custom layout for the dialog to a View
    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_dark, null);
    // inform the dialog it has a custom View
    builder.setView(view);
    // and if you need to call some method of the class
    NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) view
            .findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);

    // create the dialog from the builder then show
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

And now in my fragment, after clicking the button I try to show my number picker:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            NumberPickerCustomDialog yourDialog = new NumberPickerCustomDialog();
            yourDialog.show(fm, "some_optional_tag");
```

My layout looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center">

<net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I included library into project, copied layouts and got error:

```
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891):    at pl.package.jp.Me.NumberPickerCustomDialog.onCreateDialog(NumberPickerCustomDialog.java:26)
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891):    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:295)
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
04-17 11:33:28.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10891):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. This library requires defining styles, i.e.:

```
<style name="SampleTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item>
</style>

<style name="SampleTheme.Light" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.Light.NumberPicker</item>
</style>
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml, style must be defined for activity, where you want to use your custom number picker:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
        android:theme="@style/SampleTheme.Light">

</activity>
```