# Can android-numberpicker be instantiated as a View?

Tags: java, android

[android-numberpicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker) can be initiated with startActivity to launch an Activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LightThemeActivity.class));
```

Can it be initiated as the view of an AlertDialog? That is, can it be instantiated as a View, which can then be provided as input to setView? E.g., something like:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
View view = ... //instantiate android-numberpicker as a view
builder.setView(view);
```

where the ... is filled in.

**EDIT**

AndroidManifest.xml contains

```
<activity android:name="com.example.LightThemeActivity"
          android:theme="@style/SampleTheme.Light" />
```

I think this must be relevant, since removing it means that startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LightThemeActivity.class)) doesn't work.

**SOLUTION**

The following code (in *MainActivity.java*) initiates NumberPicker as the view of an AlertDialog:

```
NumberPicker np = new NumberPicker(MainActivity.this);
np.setMaxValue(20);
np.setMinValue(0);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setView(np);
builder.show();
```

You'll also need the following in your (in *AndroidManifest.xml*)

```
<activity android:name="example.MainActivity"
          android:theme="@style/SampleTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I was missing *android:theme="@style/SampleTheme"*.

**QUESTION**

Why does

```
getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_light, null)
```

produce an inflation exception?

**ANSWER**

Given that the style issue has been fixed, the above no longer throws an exception. Accordingly, an alternative solution is as follows:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.activity_light, null);
NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
numberPicker.setMaxValue(20);
numberPicker.setMinValue(0);

builder.setView(view);
```

**REFERENCES**

The following topics seem to be related:

[Using SimonVT number picker and unable to inflate xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987469/using-simonvt-number-picker-and-unable-to-inflate-xml)
[Custom number picker inside fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056940/custom-number-picker-inside-fragment)

**THANKS**

I am very grateful to [njzk2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671543/njzk2) for the guidance.

Comment: Yes, it's a LinearLayout.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's something they could have just tried doing.

Comment: CaseyB, I have tried.

Comment: Did it work?  What specific problems did you have?

Comment: The above code is incomplete. I don't know what the "..." should be.

Comment: read the doc, it is a view.

Comment: @njzk2, yes, that has been noted. But that doesn't help -- unless you know how to construct a view without causing a InflateException.

Comment: if you have an exception, post the stacktrace. (it also have a constructor: `new NumberPicker(MainActivity.this)` should do).

Comment: `Requires adding a single attribute to your theme.` did you do that?

Comment: @njzk2, wow! That worked*, thanks. (You probably wouldn't believe how long I have been trying to get it running.)

Comment: *after I made a change to the manifest. I'll post the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a subclass of `View`.

And because it's a subclass of `View` you can just do this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
NumberPicker nb = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_light, null);
builder.setView(nb);
```

Comment: As an example, 

View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_light, null);

causes an InflateException.

Comment: Does **activity_light.xml** exist in your **layout** folder?

Comment: Yes, activity_light.xml is in the layout folder. Moreover, startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LightThemeActivity.class)); correctly displays android-numberpicker.

Comment: that would probably be `MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater()`, from the rest of the code.